# How to access SLDS icons from a lightning component Javascript controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, jquery, slds

I am needing a switch statement, and depending on the type of file uploaded, I want to change the background of the uploader to represent the file type (pdf, doc, txt, etc...).

So, `<lightning:icon iconName="doctype:pdf" />` in the component doesn't really work since the icon is just there...

How do I, in the javascript controller of a Lightning component, access these icons and set the background of an element, or src of an image to these icons programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assets for Lightning are stored under "/apexpages/slds/latest/"; just get the icon part from the SLDS documentation for Icons with this path prepended to the file URL.

Answer (score 3):

Bind `iconName` as an attribute. So:

`<aura:attribute name="calculatedIconName" type="string"/>`

`<lightning:icon iconName="{! v.calculatedIconName }" />`

Then set it after uploading function resolves.

Comment: That does work, and gets closer to what I am after. However, I am wanting to set the background of an element to an SLDS icon. I would prefer to use the built in SLDS icons instead of creating some static resource to house all the images.

Comment: ah, in that instance i would think you would want to host SLDS icons in a static image on the off chance salesforce changes their url to the direct icon link the other poster was referring to.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that as well, that it may be wise to host them in a static resource to prevent losing them if that url does ever change. But at the moment the URL sfdcfox posted will suffice. Thank you for the help. Your post is a nice trick that I'll have to remember.